# $ undefined even jquery is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

OK, here's my issue
I use following page to get the user timezone

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jstz-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="tz-form" action="{{ URL::to('/') }}" method="post">
            <input id="tz" type="hidden" name="timezone" value="">
        </form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var timezone = jstz.determine();
                $('#tz').val(timezone.name());
                $('#tz-form').submit();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I run the application firebug shows me following errors

> 1. SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' html tag
> 2. ReferenceError: PhpDebugBar is not defined    var phpdebugbar = new
>      PhpDebugBar.DebugBar(); TypeError: $ is not a function
> 3. $('#tz').val(timezone.name());

I'm using laravel 5.1 and barryvdh/laravel-debugbar.
Thank you

Comment: The paths to the JS libraries seems to be wrong. Laravel shows a 404 document which results in a JavaScript error.

Comment: JS libraries loading, firebug "Net" panel 200OK

Comment: Do you have html tags in js file? The first error looks like so.

Comment: Wouldn't this piece of code get stuck in a forever post-reload-page loop, if visiting `/`?

Comment: No, it shows the first tag in on the html file.

Comment: Eric, No I handled it through the controller ;)

Comment: I don't think so this is an error related to this piece of code.

Comment: "firebug "Net" panel 200OK". Open the JS path _directly_ and see the result.

Comment: Vohuman, it loads perfectly even when I opened it directly

Comment: You may have a problem in your view, it seems like the "noconflict" code is not loaded into your page. You should see something like "<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>", do you ?

Comment: Yup. I think debugbar automatically adds it into the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, this happens from the

> jQuery.noConflict(true);

as [Arrakeen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957264/undefined-even-jquery-is-loaded#comment49948183_30957264) said, that adds automatically to the page

so I added change my script to this and it worked. :)

```
    <script>
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
        jq(document).ready(function(){
            var timezone = jstz.determine();
            jq('#tz').val(timezone.name());
            jq('#tz-form').submit();
        });
    </script>
```